# Facebook Unity AppRequest OGActionType?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Hello I am using the following code to make App Request to ask my friends for lives:

```
FB.AppRequest(
        "Will you Send me a Free Life?",
        Facebook.OGActionType.AskFor,
        objectId,
        null,
        "FreeLife",
        "GameName",
        AppRequestCallback
        );
```

where **objectId** is the id I got when I created a new object from the Object Browser at Facebook Developers.

When I run it on iOS. I receive the following Error:

```
{"error_code":"100","error_message":"Object+type+'Game'+for+ID+'objectId'+is+not+owned+by+this+app."}
```

Can anyone guide me how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: Maybe you are missing some steps? Check out my blog post, and see if you followed everything in there:

http://www.bigfootgaming.net/blog/tutorials/facebook-open-graph-objects-in-unity3d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an object in graph api and then also create that object through object browser. Note: Make sure is_scraped property is false for object created through object browser.